# How to invalidate form if user provides a bad image URL?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-validate

I am having a couple of problems with jQuery form field validation and image URLs.

1. I can't successfully block form submission if an apparently valid URL returns a bad response.
2. I can't see how to catch and handle warnings/exceptions arising from testing the URL.

The app is a pop up form out of a Google Spreadsheet, using Google Apps Script to prepare data, and jQuery to present it in the displayed HTML.

I need to record the hyperlink to a remote image which may or may not be an HTTPS URL  I also need to get and record the image dimensions. I need to block form submission until I can successfully save the image's dimensions.

---

### The HTML :

```
<div id="divEditImageURL">
  Image URL : <input id="editImageURL" title="ImageURL" name="val_ImageURL">
  <div id="divImageURLresult"></div>
</div>
```

---

### The Javascript :

```
$("#WorkOrderEditor").validate({
   rules: {
       val_WorkOrderNumber: "required"
     , val_ImageURL: {
         required: true,
         url: true
       }
    }
   , messages: {
        val_WorkOrderNumber: "Please provide a valid work order number."
      , val_ImageURL: "Please provide the hyperlink to an image of the damage."
     }
   , submitHandler: function(form) {
      saveEditedWorkOrder();
  }
});

$( "#editImageURL" ).change(function() {
    var url = $( this ).val();
    console.log( "change() : " + url);
    $('<img/>').attr('src', url).on("load", function() {
         var img_dims = {w:this.width, h:this.height};
         console.log( "load() image width : " + img_dims.h + ":" + img_dims.w); 
         $('#editImageHeight').val(img_dims.h);
         $('#editImageWidth').val(img_dims.w);
         $('#divImageURLresult').html("Height : " + img_dims.h + ". Width : " + img_dims.w);
    }).error(function() { 
         console.log( "load() Bad URL "); 
         $('#editImageURL').val('Bad URL : ' + url);
         $('#editImageURL')[0].setCustomValidity("Uh Oh!");
         console.log( "load() Bad URL "); 
    });
});
```

---

### Example good value log :

> change() : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PROtC.png
>
> The page at
>   'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RHHD2zoI5j_aIBipYwQ7KUuKKxQHMjxLYmzjJv3En8s/edit#gid=709705542'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from
>   'https://i.stack.imgur.com/PROtC.png': this content should also be loaded
>   over HTTPS.
>
> load() image width : 253:462

---

### Example bad value log :

> change() : http://i.imgur.com/Xgng8S9.pig
>
> The page at
>   'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RHHD2zoI5j_aIBipYwQ7KUuKKxQHMjxLYmzjJv3En8s/edit#gid=709705542'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from
>   'http://i.imgur.com/Xgng8S9.pig': this content should also be loaded
>   over HTTPS.
>
> GET http://imgur.com/Xgng8S9.pig 404 (Not Found)
>
> load() Bad URL
>
> undefined is not a function

Note: The value of field '#editImageURL' **does** get replaced with "Bad URL : http://imgur.com/Xgng8S9.pig" but the second console log line is never executed.

---

### My questions :

1. Why does "*$('#editImageURL')[0].setCustomValidity('Uh Oh!');*" throw "undefined is not a function" and what are my alternatives for blocking form submission?
2. How can I catch and suppress console logs like "this content should also be loaded over HTTPS"? (for my app HTTP URLs are to be expected, but the app itself has to be HTTPS)

Comment: Instead of using jQuery Validate along-side a completely separate validation routine, why don't you use the methods provided by this plugin?  You can use `remote` to use a server-side function to validate or you could use `addMethod()` to write a custom rule.  By working within the plugin, you are guaranteed to block form submission until you get what you need (as long as JavaScript isn't bypassed or disabled).

Comment: Sorry?  What do you mean by "use the methods provided by this plugin?"  Which plugin is that?

Comment: um, the only plugin used in your question... the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: Aha, The phrase "Instead of using jQuery Validate . . " confused me.  I'd have  more easily understood "Instead of using a completely separate validation routine along-side jQuery Validate, why don't you use the methods it provides?".  So I should read up on the addMethod() function of jQuery Validate.  Will do.  Thanks.

Comment: Your suggestion is excellent -- but it leads me to a new problem.  The validator tests the rule after every keystroke! Testing a URL for every variant as the user types is bad. How do I run the rule only upon onfocusout ?

Comment: [Please review documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).  Simply use the `onkeyup: false` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the jQuery Validate plugin along-side a completely separate validation routine, why don't you use the methods provided by this plugin? You can use [the `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) to test against a server-side script or [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to write a custom rule. By working within the plugin, you are guaranteed to block form submission until you get what you need (as long as JavaScript isn't bypassed or disabled).

You can also use the `onkeyup: false` option to only validate on focus out.

See documentation here:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

---

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25327501/594235) for how the OP ultimately applied my suggestion and solved this issue.

Comment: I'll set yours to be the correct answer if you update yours with a suggestion to future readers that they refer to mine for how I finally solved everything.

Answer (score 1):

Sparky pointed me to the right answer, but left me wrestling with the correct way to handle the image load callback.

As far as I can tell, custom validation rules must return immediately, which does not allow for making a remote call and waiting for an embedded callback.

I realized that my added validation would have to always return 'true', and validate/invalidate some other field instead; one of the image dimensions being the logical candidate.  Also, I don't want to display the image dimension fields, so I write the values to a text <div> and set its CSS class to reflect the final validation state.

Here's the final result code, interspersed with comments, for the first part of my questions.
I'm going to turn the second part into a new question.

---

### HTML

```
<div id="divEditImageURL">
    Image URL : <input id="editImageURL" title="ImageURL" name="val_ImageURL">
    <div id="divImageURLresult"></div>
</div>

<div id="divEditImageHeight"  class="label">
    Image Height : <input id="editImageHeight" title="ImageHeight" name="val_ImageHeight">
</div>

<div id="divEditImageWidth">
    Image Width : <input id="editImageWidth" title="ImageWidth" name="val_ImageWidth">
</div>
```

---

### Javascript

```
/*  Invalidate the image height immedately upon any change to the image URL  */
$( "#editImageURL" ).change(function() {
  $('#editImageHeight').val("Unknown");
});

/*  Rather than show these numbers in disabled data entry */
/*    fields, 'divImageURLresult' will be shown instead.  */
$( "#divEditImageHeight" ).hide();
$( "#divEditImageWidth" ).hide();

/*   Vew validation rule added to jQuery Validation */
$.validator.addMethod(
      "remoteImage"  // This is the name of the new rule, applied to 'val_ImageURL' below.
    , function (url, element) {
        $('#divImageURLresult').removeClass("invalid").removeClass("validated"); // Clear previous simulated validation results
        $('<img/>').attr('src', url).on("load", function() {
           $('#editImageHeight').val(this.height);
           $('#editImageWidth').val(this.width);
           $('#divImageURLresult').html("Height : " + this.height + ". Width : " + this.width);
          $('#divImageURLresult').addClass("validated");  // Simulated validation result
        }).error(function() { 
           $('#editImageHeight').val("Unknown"); // Force validation to fail. Height can only be a number.
           $('#divImageURLresult').html("Not an image.");
           $('#divImageURLresult').addClass("invalid");  // Simulated validation result
        });
        return true;  // Always return true since we get here before the image load callback returns.
      }
    , "");


$("#WorkOrderEditor").validate({
   // Specify the validation rules
   rules: {
       val_WorkOrderNumber: "required"
     , val_ImageURL: {
           required: true
         , url: true          // Must ba a valid URL
         , remoteImage: true  //  This is the new rule added above, it always tests
       }                      //  valid, but it puts the load result in editImageHeight 
     , val_ImageHeight: {
         required: true,
         number: true          // Must ba a valid integer
       }
     , val_ImageWidth: {
         required: true,
         number: true          // Must ba a valid integer
       }
    }

   , messages: {
        val_WorkOrderNumber: "Please provide a valid work order number."
      , val_ImageURL: "Please provide the hyperlink to an image of the required work."
      , val_ImageHeight: "The URL does not point to a valid image."
     }
   , errorClass: "invalid"
   , onkeyup: false  //  Do NOT validate on every key stroke
   , ignore: []      //  Ignore "hidden" state of fields, and validate them anyway.
   , submitHandler: function(form) {
      saveEditedWorkOrder();
  }
});
```

---

To be fair, considering all the help he provided, I set Sparky's answer to be the correct one.  He has made his answer point to this one so that future readers know that it has tried and tested example code. Up Votes, if this helps you, help others find it and are always appreciated :-)